# Twilio API not receiving current location via WhatsApp channel

Tags: location, twilio, media, whatsapp

I am currently building a bot using Twilio's WhatsApp integration with Twilio Studio. I need users to be able to share their current location with the bot, but found that if I send a location through WhatsApp, the body of the message that is sent to Twilio Studio is blank. I have tested other scenarios, such as sending a textual message, images, etc. and it all works fine, except when sharing location messages.

Does anyone know if WhatsApp location messages are currently not supported by Twilio?

Below is an example of the trigger message that is received by Twilio Studio whenever I send my current location through WhatsApp.

Thanks!

```
{
 "contact": {
   "channel": {
     "address": "whatsapp:+34..."
   }
 },
 "trigger": {
   "message": {
     "ApiVersion": "2010-04-01",
     "SmsSid": "SM32631478ffaaf810cf5976df7586708f",
     "SmsStatus": "received",
     "SmsMessageSid": "SM32631478ffaaf810cf5976df7586708f",
     "NumSegments": "1",
     "From": "whatsapp:+34...",
     "To": "whatsapp:+1...",
     "MessageSid": "SM32631478ffaaf810cf5976df7586708f",
     "Body": "",
     "AccountSid": "ACc66461614830932cb12fdc6ab9d1d0a7",
     "NumMedia": "0"
   }
 },
 "widgets": {},
 "flow": {
   "flow_sid": "FWf8aae0f75a993b4a497aa6a569a54114",
   "channel": {
     "address": "whatsapp:+1..."
   },
   "sid": "FN522a44cadf024dc69d055c6690244db0"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just received an answer from Twilio that clarifies this is not something that Twilio supports at this stage. They do not currently have any ETA for when this feature will be available.

Comment: Any chance you found a way around this?
Struggling on the same issue

Answer (score 2):

If a location is present in your whatsApp text you can fetch it the same way you fetch your body

```
if (req.body.Latitude && req.body.Longitude) {
console.log('Whatsapp location received...');
console.log(req.body.Latitude + ', ' + req.body.Longitude);
 }
```